# dataGridView checkbox column "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm trying to capture the state of cells of a checkbox-column in a dataGridView (enabled/disabled) in the dataGridView_CellEndEdit event of a Windows Form, as such:

```
 private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
       { 
          switch ((bool)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value)
               {
                 case true:
                    //do something
                    break;
                 case false:
                    //do something else
                    break;
                 default:
                    break;
               }
       }
  }
```

This works apart from one case; when I click in any part of the checkbox cell other than the white rectangle (say for example that I missed), and then try to click something else, I get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This error occurs on this line:

```
switch ((bool)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//put before the switch 
if (e.RowIndex<0 || dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex] ==null || dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value ==null )
{
//cannot determine what was selected , you could return or do something else . . .
return;
}
```